# Need help converting SQL to EF4 please

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I need help converting this SQL statement, into EF4:

```
Select Posts.PostID, Post, Comment
from Posts left join
 Comments on posts.PostID = Comments.PostID
    Where CommentID not in 
    (
     Select PostID
     from Votes
     where VoteTypeID = 4 --4 = flagged comment type
    )
```

In my database, the Votes table stores either the PostID of reported posts, or CommentID of reported comments in the column Votes.PostID

Thanks in advance!

Comment: confused do you want help with the linq-to-entities statement or how to create the EDMX model to support this SQL?

Comment: I have the edmx model already, just not sure where to put the .Any()s and the .Where()s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (var context = new Model1Container())
{
  var posts = context.Posts.
    All((p)=> p.Votes.All((v) => v.VoteTypeId!=4));

  //Or
  var posts2 = from p in context.Posts
          where p.Votes.All((v)=> v.VoteTypeId != 4)
          select p;                
}
```

Update:
Based on my understanding you want all the posts, but for each post, you want to filter its comments, if that's the case, you could use [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx):

```
var posts =
  context.Posts.
  //Include("Comments").
    ToDictionary(
      (p) => p, 
      (p) => p.Comments.Where((c)=> c.Votes.All((v) => v.VoteTypeId !=4))
    );

foreach (var item in posts)
{
  var post = item.Key;
  var comments = item.Value;
}
```

Note: uncomment the [`Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) method if lazy-loading is disabled, and you explicitly want to eager-load the comments in this query.

Update2:

```
var postsCollection = posts.Keys.ToArray();
var commentsCollection = posts.Values.ToArray();
```

Comment: I think this one is close, but almost.  This page will show posts and all the comments that aren't of type 4. Wouldn't this query filter the posts of type 4?  I need it to only filter votes on comments.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, filtering comments.  Then I should pass the IDictionary to my view?

Comment: You could either pass the IDictionary to the view, or if you use master-detail separate viewes, you can give each view it's collection, I've updated my answer again.

Comment: I am not sure whether you use WPF, ASP.NET, Windows-forms to represent your data, I could help you more if you'll provide me with some info.
Please don't forget to vote and mark my post as answer if that helped you out.

Comment: Thanks, I marked yours as the answer.  After about 10+ years of SQL, LINQ/EF is a bit difficult to get into.

Comment: Yep. the idea getting used to is: think OOP (entities, classes, objects, [nav-ptoperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738520.aspx)) rather than think about IDs and relations.

Comment: how do I pass two collections to my View?

Comment: I said if you have two views, 1 for master and 1 for details (based on the selected item in master-view) you can seperate them as in Update2 in my post.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to determine without seeing your Model. But this should get you started.
If you would like you can post a picture of your model or the EDMX and I can take a better look at this.

```
var myPosts = from p in posts
              where !p.Comments.Any(c => c.Votes.VoteID != 4)
                PostId = p.PostId,
                //other field needed here
              };
```

Comment: Being a new member, I can't post an image.  But in my EDMX, the Votes table relates to both the posts and comments table.  And, I only need votes to be filtered when the votetypeid is 4.

Comment: @Ken Eldridge  Ok I updated the answer.  Give it a try. I believe this is what you want.